# Not cross-domain. XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:portNo1 . Origin localhost:portNo2 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I have a server created from BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer in Python at localhost:portNo1

Client-side is at localhost:portNo2 and at client-side, I am making a jQuery $.ajax POST request like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:portNo1",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json_data
    });
```

At server side, server gets the data from client and replies with its data.

```
def do_POST(self):
    # Get client data
    length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))        
    data_string = self.rfile.read(length)
    print data_string;        
    # Create response object        
    jsonObjStr = json.dumps(jsonObj);
    self.send_response(200)        
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(jsonObjStr);
```

What happens is that server is getting the data I sent, but there is no reply to the client and the callback at the fail event of $.ajax object executes at the client-side(error msg). I debugged and verified there is nothing with jsonObj. But I cannot see what is inside self.wfile object.

At the JS console, I get the following error also (it shows up at the JS console of Google Chrome and it doesn't show up in Firefox JS console):

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:portNo1 . Origin localhost:portNo2 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.                          client.html:1`

The JS console at Google Chrome points to html file, but that didn't make sense for me, either.

I checked the website and it seems that the error is generally caused due to cross-domain requests. However, I am communicating from one localhost port to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's the problem. Cross-origin restrictions do not allow you to communicate across ports without sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

A better solution would be to use Nginx or some other webserver to reverse proxy those two running applications to the same domain and port.